# How to use Transition Manager of DevExpress in C#?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I want to add transitional effects to my form and let my panels come and go smoothly. I just found this component named "`Transition Manager`"(DevExpress) and I think it can help, but I don't know how.

I've already chose the control I want to fade away , but no visible success.
When I code like this:

```
transitionManager1.StartTransition(panel2);
```

I get error telling me that thread.cs can't be found in DevExpress.Utils!!

this component looks like this when added to `windows form`:

[image: Transition Manager]

PS: If you know any component which is a borderless panel and features transitions, let me know please. Thanks.

Comment: You could check out the DevExpress documentation - [TransitionManager Class](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.Animation.TransitionManager).

Answer (score 2):

Dev express has build-in transition control on several UI controls. Please check the properties of the specific control. eg:
this screenshot demonstrates the transition of two tab panel,

[image]

or you need provide the more details

Comment: I checked this component and its transition looks great to me, but there's a problem, it contains a "too visible" border.
As I want to use it in  my main form of the application, it looks somehow bad. is there any solution to hide the border or maybe another component? Anyway thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi, can you please give me a screenshot?